# How to overcome "No destination with id '<destination id>' is registered with any service"

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I am looking for suggestion about the error called

> "No destination with id '<destination id>' is registered with any service."

this error is coming when I try to connect the remote method in Java from flex.

Comment: @ Hari kanna ...After almost seven years... I reckon you should award Constantiner for posting best answer is a little late but you should do it anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have not synchronized your `remoting-config.xml` of server and client version. The server version just hasn't this destination there.

Comment: I did it. Can u tel about reason and rectification any way??

Comment: I suppose you should use the same `remoting-config.xml` and `services-config.xml` i server project and in Flex project. Then you should rebuild both and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for "No destination with id '' is registered with any service" problem is that you have to make sure your destination definition is added in your:

> C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\flex\messaging-config.xml

Secondly, if you are deploying it on a ColdFusion Server, then you have to make sure exact same definition is added in Server messaging-config.xml file as well.

This should solve this problem.

While we are at it, wanted to point another possible gotcha.

if your Server is using SSL protocol i.e. it has https:// rather than http://, Then within your  definition block in messaging-config.xml, you have to add appropriate secure channels in  section. You can find all available channel definitions in

> C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\flex\services-config.xml